# Why does the Link Attribute fail?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting, but the link at the end [Present Perfect vs Present + Adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/182401/50720) still fails.

Comment: You got it reversed. The link description should be in the square brackets, and link location in round brackets. I fixed it for you, take a look and approve the edit if you want.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you! Approved. Please feel free to answer for which I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the order of the markdown elements reversed.

Correct link is in the format:

```
[description](target location)
```

while yours was:

```
[target location](description)
```